# NextResponse.json possibly corrupting json syntax

Tags: javascript, json, next.js

Running nextjs 13.5.3 and working an api route handler under /app

The route handler has a few functions but primarily fetches from a cms and returns the response. IDs appear on the client side hashed, so one of its functions is to unhash ids from a request, and hash them in the response. For the sake of debugging and solving this problem, I am now just manually changing the id values to a string, from an integer, which is what the hashing function did.

### Problem

The client receives responses from the route handler just fine if I don't modify the response. But if I change the value of id in the route handler (for the sake of hashing it), the browser is unable to parse the response json when I attempt `const data = await response.json();`

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Expected ':' after property name in
> JSON at position 2269 (line 1 column 74)

#### Route Handler Simplified to minimal working version

```
export async function POST(request, params) {

    const serviceRes = await fetch('https://someservice.com/api');

    ... check status of response is ok ...
    ... check if json is returned and if it is, parse it ...

    const serviceData = await serviceRes.json();

    // Modify the value of id, if it exists

    if (serviceData && serviceData.data && serviceData.data.id) {
        serviceData.data.id = 'test';
    }

    const res = NextResponse.json(serviceData, {
        status: serviceRes.status,
        headers: serviceRes.headers,
    });

    return res;

}
```

#### serviceData sample, after changing id

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "asdasd", // this was an integer, like 4278
        "title": "Hello World",
        "content": "This is a test content",
        "tagging": []
    }
}
```

### Further Tests

In the route handler, just after modifying serviceData.data.id, I've added:

```
console.log("serviceData", serviceData);
console.log("stringified", JSON.stringify(serviceData));
```

And am seeing no issue with the object or json. I've validated them fine. Which is why I'm wondering if the Nextresponse.json is the issue?

The column where the issue occurs, according to the error statement is where the colon appears on the final key, tagging. The error seems to think there's no colon there, but it appears in the console logs fine. And I'm not modifying tagging, so it's an unusual situation.

I've tried testing for non-mutating versions using spread operators but the same error occurred.

Again, if I don't modify any value in serviceData, the browser parses the json fine. I'm stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was reusing the headers from serviceRes, when modifying the data. Specifically, the content-length header is now incorrect once the data has been modified.

This was tricky to pin down as there's some slightly hazy advice on this regarding content-length being recalculated when sending new responses. But as I was sending a copy of the original headers, no new content-length header was being generated by the route handler.

```
// Copy headers from the original response
let headers = new Headers(serviceRes.headers);
// Remove the Content-Length header, as it will be incorrect if we modify the response body.
// Once it's removed, it will be recalculated by either this server or the browser.
headers.delete('Content-Length');
```